# How can I receive from Azure IoT Hub messages sent by devices?

Tags: python, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I have successfully built *azure-iot-sdk-python* and I have managed to handle the device side of things:

- sending messages and reported-properties
- receiving messages and desired-properties

I can also manage devices from the service side:

- create devices, update devices
- delete devices
- manage device twins (setting tags, reading tags, setting desired-properties, getting reported-properties)

What I cannot find is how to access the Events (`messages/events`) endpoint using *azure-iot-sdk-python* and read the messages sent by the devices. How do I do that?

Comment: Currently you can't do this because [Event Hubs does not support telemetry in Python yet.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-python-getstarted#receive-messages-from-your-simulated-device)

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Thanks; I was hoping that the documentation was outdated. Leaving the question open for the future.

Comment: Reading device to cloud messages directly from IoT Hub implies reading from an event hub endpoint. The Event Hubs team has not yet published an official SDK for Python (see other languages here:https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs), but you might want to try this early version: https://github.com/azure/azure-event-hubs-python